# Django Performance / Memory usage

Tags: django, performance, apache, memory, nginx

I am running an alpha version of my app on a EC2 Small instance (1.7 GB RAM) with postgres and apache (wsgi-mod not as daemon but directly) on it.

Performance is alright, but it could be better. I am also worried about memory usage if too many test users would join.

Is it wise to switch from Apache to nginx server? Has any Django developer done that and is happier with the results? Any other tips on the way are also welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't this be on server fault?

Comment: switched a while ago - best step I've done. Performance and RAM usage is a dream. Apps are served via Gunicorn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are using nginx together with our Django app in a [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) server. The performance is quite good so far, but I have not done any direct comparisons with an Apache setup. Memory usage is quite small, nginx takes about 10MB memory and gunicorn about 150MB (but it also servers more than one app). Of course this may vary from app to app.

I would suggest to simply give it a try, it should be quite easy to set up following some tutorials on the web and/or on the gunicorn website. Also get some comparable test case and use some kind of monitoring software like [munin](http://www.munin-monitoring.org) to see changes over time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The numbers are very interesting. I wonder if I could be cheap and even go with a cheaper Micro Ec2 instance (613 MB). I have only one app and little money - being a startup. :) I could give it a shot and see if I get memory overflow. I did some research today, what is your opinion about uWSGI, which is an alternative to gunicorn is that correct? Also thanks for munin. Could come in very handy.

Comment: Keep in mind that micro instances do not have a fixed amount of CPU allocated. But develop a set of realistic tests and check, maybe it is enough! No personal experience about uWSGI though, sorry.

Comment: +1 for your advice. true. Micro instances work best in small bursts, within that burst they get actually 2 cpus assigned. Maybe I should stay with small instance after all. At least one cpu assigned continuously. One last question, do you keep the DB (postgres or mysql) on the same instance? thanks

Comment: Check out [linode](http://www.linode.com/?r=0b098be1577dc5c0871caeea315e75a431acd7e9). For smaller instances their price/performance ratio is very interesting (disclaimer: the link has my referral code, but I'm actually a very satisfied customer).

Comment: Kave, I am using RDS instead of a self-hosted mysql.

Comment: @j0nes Thanks. A pity Amazon doesn't offer Postgres as RDS. But MySQL is also an option I might look into before going final release. Have you been using South with MySQL RDS without any problems?

Comment: Yes, South works without any problems. If in doubt, just fire up a RDS server and test if it also works for your application.

Comment: @j0nes yeah I just fired up an RDS. Did you still have to install MySQL on your ec2, even though you won't be using the local one and would be connecting to the remote one anyway? It is a shame because it would use unnecessary memory away from the ec2.

Comment: No, but you will have to install the necessary libraries and/or the mysql commandline client.

Comment: yeah, `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` would do it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Why aren't you using daemon mode of mod_wsgi? If you are using embedded mode you are setting yourself up for memory issues if you aren't careful with how you set up Apache.

Go have a read of:

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html

and also watch my PyCon talk at:

http://lanyrd.com/2012/pycon/spcdg/

Also amend your question and indicate which Apache MPM you are using and what the MPM settings are.

As to using alternatives such as gunicorn or uWSGI, for a comparable configuration, the memory requirements aren't doing to be much different as the underlying server isn't going to be what dictates how much memory is used, it is going to be your specific Python web application running on top of it. It is a common misconception that gunicorn or uWSGI somehow magically solves all the problems and that Apache can't do as well. Set Apache up properly for a Python web application and don't rely on its defaults and it is just as capable as other solutions and can provide a lot more flexibility depending on your requirements.

Very much suggest you get in place some monitoring to work out what the real issues and bottlenecks are.

Comment: +1 Thanks Graham. Your blog is very good and your speech was informative. I am still in tech-trying-phase and might stick Apache-daemon after all.  But you also mentioned in order to achieve the light-weight of nginx, Apache needed to disable some of the buildin mods. Is this difficult to achieve?

Comment: Depends on what Linux distribution you are using and whether using its Apache distro. For example http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-disable-apache-modules-under-linux-unix/ Other platforms may be a bit different. If running on Apache installation, may mean commenting out appropriate LoadModule line.

Comment: Ah apologies,  forgot to mention I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with the Apache that comes with it. So I see now how to disable them. Is there a list of all available modules I could safely disable etc?

Comment: You would have to know which modules you are using. So not a case of which are safe to disable, but which you aren't relying on with the way the Apache configuration is setup.

Answer (score 1):

I have mixed results. When the app is fast, non-blocking, nginx performs well with a smaller memory footprint. The benefit is bigger with a higher traffic.

I have a couple GIS applications that are a bit slower, in this context nginx fails miserably. My advice is: don't use nginx + wsgi on anything that can block for a few seconds.